# Exclude double input in multiple comboboxes but allow empty boxes except the first one

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 comboBoxes with the same lists for input
No doubles are allowed as an answer in these boxes. 2 boxes without input are allowed however this gives the note that 2 boxes have the same value (blank) so I want to exclude empty box (no input) for checking doubles.

I'm not a programmer, cut&paste is my tool.

Code:
'Check if input 3x ComboBox does not contain doubles

```
If Trim(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = (Me.ComboBox2.Value) Then
 Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Duplicate input in box 1 a 2"
 Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = (Me.ComboBox3.Value) Then
 Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Duplicate input in box 1 a 3"
 Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ComboBox2.Value) = (Me.ComboBox3.Value) Then
 Me.ComboBox3.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Duplicate input in box 2 a 3"
 Exit Sub
End If
```

When box 2 and 3 stay empty there shouldn't be a message for duplicate input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a second condition to your IF-statement:

```
If Trim(Me.ComboBox2.Value) = (Me.ComboBox3.Value) and (Me.ComboBox3.Value)<>"" Then
```